# How to use ResponseEntity in a switch?

Tags: spring

I have a method called handleImageBannerUpload. In this method I have a switch statement. There are 3 switch cases and each should return a different ResponseEntity:

```
switch(type){
    case "localEvent":
            try {
            LocalEvent localEvent = localEventRepository.findOne(id);
            storageService.store(file, localEvent);
            String path = localEvent.getBannerPath();
            log("FileUploadController: " + path);
            result = ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;")
                .body(path);
        }
        catch (StorageException e) {
            result = ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)               
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;")
                .body("\"" + e.getMessage() + "\"");
        }  

    case "session":
        try {
            Session session = sessionRepository.findOne(id);
            storageService.store(file, session);
            String path = session.getSessionDescriptionImagePath();
            log("FileUploadController: " + path);
            result =  ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;")
                .body(path);
        }
        catch (StorageException e) {
            result = ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)               
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;")
                .body("\"" + e.getMessage() + "\"");
        } 
    case "theme":
        try{
            Theme theme = themeRepository.findOne(id);
            storageService.store(file, theme);
            String path = theme.getThemeImagePath();
            log("FileUploadController: " + path);
            result = ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;")
                .body(path);
        }
        catch (StorageException e) {
            result = ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)               
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;")
                .body("\"" + e.getMessage() + "\"");
        }
}

return result;
```

How do I create a proper `result` variable that can return the ResponseEntity in the switch statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have a design smell that has bled into your code. You are sacrificing clarity, readability and testability in favor of a switch.

What you need are 3 concise endpoints:

```
POST /banner/event
POST /banner/theme
POST /banner/template
```

From there you should adhere to the single responsibility principle so that each corresponding controller method is short and concise.